# How to remove identical rows in a large data.frame

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

```
GN  PN  
a   3.4   
a   3.4   
a   9.8   
d   8.4   
e   9 
e   6.5
```

I would like the following output:

```
GN  PN  
a   3.4   
a   9.8   
d   8.4   
e   9 
e   6.5
```

(the identical rows will be removed!)

I' m trying to use the code posted in: [multiple columns comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319935/multiple-columns-comparison) but without success because the replicated line (a 3.4) still remains. I have a large data.frame (about 66.000 rows and 10 columns).

The real case:

```
 GN     SP                PN
A1CF   52573692   TCGA-B6-A0RS-01A-11D-A099
A1CF   52595854   TCGA-BH-A0HP-01A-12D-A099 
A1CF   52595854   TCGA-BH-A0HP-01A-12D-A099
A1CF   52595937   TCGA-BH-A18P-01A-11D-A12B
A2BP1  7568361    TCGA-D8-A1JN-01A-11D-A13L
A2BP1  7102099    TCGA-E2-A1BC-01A-11D-A14G
A2BP1  7102099    TCGA-E2-A1BC-01A-11D-A14G
A2BP1  7383011    TCGA-AR-A1AJ-01A-21D-A12Q
A2BP1  7383011    TCGA-AR-A1AJ-01A-21D-A12Q
A2BP1  7568188    TCGA-BH-A18J-01A-11D-A12B
A2BP1  7629860    TCGA-AO-A03O-01A-11W-A019
A2BP1  7629860    TCGA-AO-A03O-01A-11W-A019
```

Comment: Sorry, but what's wrong with unique(df) in your real case ?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944816/unique-on-a-dataframe-with-only-selected-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use :

```
 unique(df)
```

Which gives :

```
  GN  PN
1  a 3.4
3  a 9.8
4  d 8.4
5  e 9.0
6  e 6.5
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work..

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more ? It works well on your example here...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `new.df=subset(df,!duplicate(df))`

Comment: just posted the real case!